# How to reuse an output of a function?

Tags: python

I'm trying to reuse an output of a time-consuming function in other functions without re-run it again.
example:

```
%%time
def func1():
    sleep(100)
    y = 123
    return y
func1()
```

Wall time: 100 s

```
%%time 
def func2():
    x = func1()
    return x
func2()
```

Wall time: 100 s

I want func2 to reuse the output of fun1 without waiting for another 100 all over again.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) for the task:

```
from time import sleep
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache
def func1():
    sleep(3)
    y = 123
    return y

print(func1())  # <-- this waits 3 seconds
print(func1())  # <-- this is printed immediately
```

Comment: It seems to be a good solution for my needs. thank you! but what is the best alternative in case the function is not pure? let's say every x runs I need to receive a different output? cuz the lru_cache will not be changed until the script will terminate and restart, am I correct?

Comment: @mor2778 `lru_cache` caches the function based on function parameters. So if you give your function different parameter, it caches the output along this parameter.

Comment: Got ya. thank you very much. I will start digging a little bit more on lur_cache :)